# How do you test against Internet Explorer on a selenium grid?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, selenium, jenkins, selenium-grid2

I'm setting up a selenium grid by running the hub and nodes as windows services. I'm having no issues with Chrome or FireFox but I am with IE and from what I see IEDriverServer doesn't support being run as a windows service or in the background and is inconsistent as far as testing goes.

So how do people/companies generally test against IE on a selenium grid for automated regression testing ?

Answer (score 1):

My organization has attempted to run the grid as a service supporting IE. Over the period of several months, we have had numerous reports from users logging inexplicable issues occurring only on the enterprise grid. Through extensive troubleshooting, we determined that the issues only occurred while the grid was being run as a service.

We are currently piloting both linux-based grid hosting and an external grid provider, such as SauceLabs.